# Am I too old (school) for my job?

Tags: software-engineering

I'm working as a full stack software engineer for about 10 years, but recently I started wondering if I am actually suited for that profession (I'm currently 42 years old, if that matters)....

I graduated in CS in 2005, but only managed to work in that field as of 2013. At first I really did enjoy that job, but some developments in the engineering world make me feel like I'm completely out of sync with what's going on.

For example, it feels like utilizing microservice architecture with orchestration (likely Kubernetes) is the way to go in most places nowadays, whereas I feel like about 80% of all projects do not profit enough from the merits that they would warrant the additional overhead. I usually prefer going with monolithic, or at least basic client-server architecture until the need for changing the architecture comes apparent, especially if the project is run by me alone or a very small team.

I do encounter similar feelings towards database architecture, where it fells like nowadays databases are seen as nothing more than a mere key/value store to throw in some data and not worry too much about consistency, where I myself am a strong proponent of data modelling and utilizing SQL databases as far as possible, trying to ensure data consistency on a database level (my train of thought is whatever I allow into my database will at some point end up coming in, and if my data messes up I will have a very hard time fixing it up).

However, most of the time when discussing developing with my peers it feels like I'm about the only one with these kind of views, and that really makes me wonder whether I might be completely wrong in my profession (sometimes I feel like there might be fields outside of app development where my way of thinking might be better applicable, but then again, I wouldn't have any idea on how to get into there...).

I know this is probably a bad question as mostly opinion based, but I still would be interested if there are others experiencing similar feelings, and how they managed to handle it.

Comment: For what it's worth, IBM started as an enthusiastic supporter of microservices, then realized that they are really only of use when trying to open up APIs into an unmaintainable code monolith, and NOT a good way to build new applications, no matter how pretty the textbook examples may seem.  (There have been many past attempts at assembling code from plug-in components, some of which were IBM's, which all came to much the same conclusion. When's the last time you heard someone mention java beanboxes?)

Comment: Monoliths, micro services, SQL, No-SQL,... they all have their purpose. Your goal as an engineer should be to know what tools are available to you and use the right one for the problem you're trying to solve. Quite often this is not a purely technical decision, but involves business as well.

Amazon recently made a blog post about how they switched back to a monolith for one of their services: https://www.primevideotech.com/video-streaming/scaling-up-the-prime-video-audio-video-monitoring-service-and-reducing-costs-by-90.

Comment: I'd say there's stacks of old infrastructure that we've barely got off cobol or fortran - I think there's a niche for people who don't want to update skills, for sure, and that niche might only get more profitable. 

Database work is a really nice example - stuff is fast enough, for most consumer applications, that treating a db like a disposable key/value store is fine. But when you get into higher performance demands, db architecture starts to matter again. On old systems, it might be vital.

Comment: That said, I'll go to the barricades for docker. Having my dev environment extremely similar to prod is too nice to give up. The lack of stress over updates, too, is super nice.

Comment: Microservices are only really useful if there is cause for separation. Like if you want to use different programming languages or you have multiple teams working on a large project. Or you want to share services across different applications. It's divide and conquer on a higher level. Nothing wrong with a monolith for simple applications.

Comment: @lupe Also separation between frontend logic and backend logic by writing JS applications with Angular/React/Vue/backbone really is something I don't want to miss anymore. Much better than generating HTML on the server.

Comment: @seg yep, that too - so much nicer

Comment: It depends. How *big* (for various definitions of big) is your company/project? I work at a Fortune 50 company and there are facets of our business that absolutely benefit from k8s and NOSQL. But this is the first/only place I've ever worked where that was the case, every other place would be better served by monolithic architecture and RDBMS. Even here there are plenty of projects that don't need those. A lot of the usage of those things is what I'd call "resume driven development". You're not old just because you point out the Emperor is not, in fact, wearing clothes.

Comment: It might just be how it's written, but your description of NoSQL dbs is a bit simplistic. In a case where it would be a good fit,it *is* a mere key/value store BUT the enforced data consistency your solution would provide would be an unnecessary overhead. If you want to argue against something, I think it's better to understand the cases where it *is* suitable (apologies if you already know this, it just doesn't sound like in your question)

Comment: @Jared Smith Thanks for the comment, that basically summarizes my viewpoint pretty nicely. Most if the time I've been working with rather small companies (probably not more than 10 developers involved), where I felt splitting the application into several small pieces added so much overhead that it became difficult to handle. So basically I would not consider microservices unless running a rather large team of developers... However, I'd almost always be a strong proponent of client/server architecture (like in REST API and JS frontend)

Comment: @mattfreake To be honest in my description I was actually thinking about RDBMS (yes, I've been told by a fellow developer that they should not be considered much more than key/value stores), but you're definitely right, I'm yet to understand the use case where NoSQL databases provide an advantage over RDBMS... As I see it, the only reason I would want to use a NoSQL database is when I want to perform fulltext search on my data body, and then I would probably try to generate the NoSQL documents out of my RDBMS data...

Comment: I already got a couple of helpful answers on this topic before it was closed, so I would like to rephrase the question in a way that it can be answered less opinion based so I can have it reopened, but I don't really have any idea on how. Any advice on that would be appreciated

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau the way its written it's asking about you, *personally*. There really isn't any way we can answer that objectively. This is (or so I gathered) an AITA-style sanity check on disagreements over architecture etc. Even that reworded is going to be opinion based. For example, we use k8s for everything where I work even for dinky little internal projects. We do this even though it's overkill for most projects because it's easier for ops to document and support one deployment tool chain instead of 5-15 different ones and it builds a internal knowledge base around k8s....

Comment: ...so is that a good idea? IDK it depends on how you view the inherent tradeoffs. There could be good organizational reasons for choosing microservices and k8s and what have you as in my example above. Or not, but I would phrase it as "are these tools and architectural choices appropriate for this org and project" which makes it a technical question which is still opinion based but less so. IDK there might not really be a way to make this objective, and that's in a sense fine: not all good questions are a good fit for the stack exchange format.

Comment: @Jared Smith I get that, but my question honestly isn't really about whether the usage of those tools is right or wrong (I don't think there is a definitive answer to that, as there might be reasons for either in most cases), but rather about me having so strong opinions about these tools, and either how to cope with it, or whether it might even be a good idea to overthink my career choices because of my stubbornness(?)

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau I somehow missed or didn't get the notification some months ago about your response. "[my question is] about me having so strong opinions about these tools". Strong opinions are fine, but if you are going to plant your standard in the ground and say "I will die on this hill" you had by God be able to defend it against all comers. The failure mode I usually see for this for devs is that they are incapable or unwilling to think at the *organizational* level. You might think React.js a poor choice for any number of good technical reasons (or Java, or node, or)...

Comment: ...while it being simultaneously true that it is actually a very good choice for big-picture organizational reasons. The software org at my company *~doubled* in size during the pandemic. There is *no way* we could have done that if we weren't using a boring, popular, easy-to-hire-for stack. Note all of that applies equally to architectural decisions. So I would say keep your opinions, but make sure they're still valid outside the bubble of your current project. Run them through the gauntlet of higher-level people you trust and see what survives of them.

Answer (score 11):

> how they managed to handle it.

By just doing what they know how to do. Most newfangled infrastructure and software are just gimmicks, they do not have enough actual value in most situations to warrant a change. Some have so many overheads and hidden costs that they're an expensive pain to use when solutions already exist.

So you analyse and discard the fluff and usually end up sticking with the old and tested. My strategy is to look at the most basic solution for a problem and leave the bells and whistles for the circus performers.

Answer (score 5):

Its a great question and has much to do with the culture in your area and specific workplace.  Often times culture in your workplace spreads to others in the area as turnover in this industry is quite high.

I agree with you about SQL and overdoing some projects.  For the record I am 56 and work with some that are much older.  One really sharp guy I work with is in his 70s.  So you are not too old.

Often times, in this industry, the issue is not that you have presented a good case for your beliefs.  Sometimes decisions are made simply because others do not know the tech you are a proposing.  They have a vested interest in using their tech stack as they can appear as an expert and someone like you may not.  They would be lost in a different tech stack.

Management sometimes supports this as finding people skilled in different tech stacks can be challenging and may cost them more money.  For example, these days hiring a skilled Cobol programmer will cost big bucks.

What's the solution?  When you run your own project do it your way.  In the meantime do it their way.  Even if your project comes in sooner and under budget, you will probably be criticized.  It has happened to me and people a lot smarter than the both of us.

Good software engineers probably lie somewhere on the Autism spectrum.  As a result the industry experiences a lot of mildly anti-social behavior.  This is one of them.  Learning new tech stacks is hard and uncomfortable.

IMHO you might be getting too old to put up with this crap, but really it is a great career.  Nice pay and benefits and you mostly don't have to deal with people.

Comment: When I'm driven into a nervous wreck and to slap the side of my head repetitively, I tend to blame management, not autism. I don't think the proliferation of complexity has anything to do with autism, it has to do with the absence of training (and thus industry reliance on those who have self-taught, usually not as part of any collective of learners that helps knock the edges off people's personalities), as well as too little technological standardisation and consolidation, and too much corporate competition and interference by marketing departments.

Comment: @Steve what I mean is that as developers we tend to not deal 100% well with others.  The more in the conversation, the less likely a decent outcome.  Given that most managers were once developers well same sort of problem.

Comment: Agreed. Part of the issue is that many aspects of development require deep and sustained intellectual work and a carefully integrated result. It's like music-making in that respect - almost anyone who's any good at it has at some point clashed with others. However I think the other side is that there aren't the institutions that promote shared practices and standards. Compared to say music, most developers don't have a standard on what instruments are called, how to write down a tune, or how many keys in a scale. I think this is an industrial organisation problem, not a personality problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's a few things to consider here:

- Not all of software engineering is one monolith. Some companies — often especially larger ones where reliability and correctness are often valued more highly over moving quickly — have similar values to what you've presented here.
- I don't think there's really a right or wrong perspective here. I think different solutions can be better suited for different problems. When you're a small company that really needs to move fast to maintain a competitive edge, sometimes being broken doesn't matter so much. If you can get your feature released a month earlier, that might be worth more to the company than the fact that an engineer has to spend a week or two fixing a dodgy database after the fact... But on the flipside, if your software is dealing with financial transactions worth millions you probably don't want to be so laissez-faire.
- Some companies (IMHO correctly) see that having people with different points of view is important to allow them to potentially find solutions that they wouldn't have found had everyone thought the same way. Think about the way you're treated by your colleagues and management chain — are your disagreements civil and polite; do people still respect you as an engineer despite having different opinions to you; are your different perspectives highlighted as valuable in your evaluation meetings? If these are all true then I'm not sure I would worry too much. If some or all of them are false then maybe consider that you're not a good fit for the company you're at and would perhaps be better off moving elsewhere within the industry.